# 60603 (Fedora Cygwin 5.4.0-2) when using std::cout

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, console

I was practicing using the `auto` and `decltype` keywords.

When I tried to add 2 values and print the result, I got **60603 (Fedora Cygwin 5.4.0-2)** in the console.

I'm think that's probably the name of my compiler, right? Why did I get that? Because that's pretty confusing, as I'm only a rookie to the C++ world.

Here's the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class K>
auto test(T val1, K val2) -> decltype(val1 + val2) {
    return val1 + val2;
};

int main() {

    std::cout << test("Hello There! ", 99);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your time! And Please tell me a way to get this to actually print out *Hello There! 99*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the constant string literal `"Hello There!"` to your function you will pass a *pointer* to the first character in that string.

The type of a pointer plus an integer is a pointer, so the function returns a pointer. More precisely it returns a pointer to the 99:th element of the string literal, and since the string doesn't have 99 elements you are *way* out of bounds and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But can you tell me a way how can I get this to work?

Comment: @ThawinduAngeshTuto Well then you need to edit your question to include the expected behavior and the expected output.